# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? in react-native android

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-context, android-windowmanager

I want to show a custom view when the app is turned off or when the app is turned on, depending on the phone state.

so I use `WindowManager`. but get error message

```bash
 W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1596)
 W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:509)
 W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:133)
 W/System.err:     at com.reactnativecallerid.service.CallerIdOverlay.showRingingView(CallerIdOverlay.kt:190)
 W/System.err:     at com.reactnativecallerid.service.CallerIDService$procIncomingCallRinging$1.onSuccess(CallerIDService.kt:177)
 W/System.err:     at com.reactnativecallerid.service.CallerIDService$Companion.addEventListener(CallerIDService.kt:520)
 W/System.err:     at com.reactnativecallerid.CallerIdModule.addEventListener(CallerIdModule.kt:34)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
```

CallerIdOverlay.kt

```
package com.reactnativecallerid.service

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig
import com.reactnativecallerid.R
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.EstimationStatusCode
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.EstimationStatusCode.getStatus


class CallerIdOverlay(context: CallerIDService) {
  var mWindowManager: WindowManager? = null
  var service: CallerIDService = context
  private var mInflater: LayoutInflater? = null
  var mRootView: View? = null
  var mContentView: ViewGroup? = null
  var mLayoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams? = null
  var mLayoutRinging: View? = null
  var mViewType: CallerIDService.ViewType = CallerIDService.ViewType.NONE
  var isShown = false
    private set

  fun onCreate() {
    mWindowManager = service.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager?
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(service)
    mInflater?.let { _mInflater -> mRootView = _mInflater.inflate(R.layout.callerid, null) }
    mContentView = mRootView!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.content) as ViewGroup

    mInflater?.let { _mInflater -> mLayoutRinging = _mInflater.inflate(R.layout.callerid_ringing, mContentView, false) }
    mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.close).setOnClickListener { hideView() }

false) }
    mLayoutIdle!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.close).setOnClickListener { hideView() }
    val layoutFlag: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
    } else {
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
    }
    mLayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      layoutFlag,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
    mLayoutParams!!.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT
    mLayoutParams!!.x = 0
    mLayoutParams!!.y = 0
    mRootView!!.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
      private var initialY = 0

      private var initialTouchY = 0f
      private var sentGAEvent = false
      override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
          MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            initialY = mLayoutParams!!.y
            initialTouchY = event.rawY
            if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.RINGING) {
              mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid_over)
              mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.image).alpha = 0.8f
            } else if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.CONNECTED) {
              mLayoutConnected!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid_over)
            } else if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.IDLE) {
              mLayoutIdle!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid_over)
            }
            sentGAEvent = false
            return true
          }
          MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.RINGING) {
              mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid)
              mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.image).alpha = 1.0f
            } else if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.CONNECTED) {
              mLayoutConnected!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid)
            } else if (mViewType === CallerIDService.ViewType.IDLE) {
              mLayoutIdle!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_card)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_box_cid)
            }
            sentGAEvent = false
            return true
          }
          MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
  
            mLayoutParams!!.y = initialY + (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
            try {
              mWindowManager!!.updateViewLayout(mRootView, mLayoutParams)
            } catch (ignore: Exception) {
            }
            return true
          }
        }
        return false
      }
    })
  }

  fun onDestory() {
    try {
      isShown = false
      if (mWindowManager != null && mRootView != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          if (mRootView!!.isAttachedToWindow) {
            mWindowManager!!.removeView(mRootView)
          }
        } else {
          mWindowManager!!.removeView(mRootView)
        }
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
      service.stopForeground(true)
    }
  }

  fun showRingingView(userinfo: ICallerIdViewItem, phoneNumber: String?) {
    try {
      isShown = true
      
     //imgurls
      if (userinfo.imgurls != null && userinfo.imgurls!!.size > 0) {
        Glide.with(service).asBitmap().load(userinfo.imgurls!![0]!!.thumb_w456).into(
          BitmapImageViewTarget(mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView)
        )
      }

      //statuscode
      if (userinfo.statuscode != null && userinfo.statuscodeName != null) {
        (mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.statusname) as TextView).text =
          userinfo.statuscodeName
      }

      // phonenumber
      (mLayoutRinging!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.phonenumber) as TextView).text = phoneNumber
      mContentView!!.removeAllViews()
      mContentView!!.addView(mLayoutRinging)
      mRootView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      mViewType = CallerIDService.ViewType.RINGING
      if (mRootView!!.parent != null) {
        mWindowManager!!.removeView(mRootView)
      }
      mWindowManager!!.addView(mRootView, mLayoutParams)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }




  fun hideView() {
    try {
      isShown = false
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("CallerIdOverlay", "hideView()")
      service.stop()
      mRootView!!.visibility = View.GONE
      mViewType = CallerIDService.ViewType.NONE
      if (mRootView!!.parent != null) {
        mWindowManager!!.removeView(mRootView)
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }

  interface ICallerIdViewItem {
    val phonenumber: String?
    val statuscode: String?
    val imgurls: List<IImgurlViewItem?>?

    companion object {
      const val TYPE_REPAIR_SHOP = "shop"
      const val TYPE_TECH_SHOP = "techshop"
    }
  }

  interface IImgurlViewItem {
    val thumb_w456: String?
  }
}
```

CallerIDService.kt

```
package com.reactnativecallerid.service

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.*
import android.provider.Settings
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.bridge.*
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.reactnativecallerid.R
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.CallerIdVO
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.PushPayloadVO
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.PushPayloadVO.ActionVO
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.PushPayloadVO.ActionVO.OpenPage
import com.reactnativecallerid.model.TsReservation


class CallerIDService() : Service() {
  var overlay: CallerIdOverlay? = CallerIdOverlay(this)
  var statusCheckThread: Thread = object : Thread() {
    override fun run() {
      super.run()
      try {
        sleep(10000)
        do {
          sleep(1000)
        } while (isOnTransaction || overlay != null && overlay!!.isShown)
      } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
      }
      this@CallerIDService.stop()
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    statusCheckThread.start()
    showNoti(null)
    overlay!!.onCreate()
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    overlay!!.onDestory()
    statusCheckThread.interrupt()
  }

  override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(
      TAG,
      "onStartCommand :: action = " + intent.action + ", extras = " + bundle2string(intent.extras)
    )

    fun handleEvent(func: Unit) {
      Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        func
      }, 300)
    }


    if (intent != null) {
      when (intent.action) {
        TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED -> {
          val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
          if (state != null) {
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING == state) {
              val number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
              number?.let { handleEvent(procIncomingCallRinging(it)) }
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
              val number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
              number?.let { handleEvent(procOffhook(it)) }
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE == state && TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING == mPrevPhoneState) {
              handleEvent(procIncomingCallRejected())
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE == state && TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK == mPrevPhoneState) {
              handleEvent(procDisconnected())
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE == state) {
              if (isOnTransaction) {
                handleEvent(procDisconnected())
              } else {
                stop()
              }
            }
          }
          mPrevPhoneState = state
        }
        else -> stop()
      }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
  }

  fun stop() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "!!!!!!!!STOP SERVICE!!!!!!!")
    stopSelf()
  }

  private fun startTransaction(trid: String?, phonenumber: String?) {
    if (trid == null || trid.isEmpty() || phonenumber == null || phonenumber.isEmpty()) {
      return
    }
    mCurrentTrid = trid
    mCurrentPhoneNumber = phonenumber
  }

  private fun endTransaction() {
    mCurrentTrid = null
    mCurrentPhoneNumber = null
  }

  private val isOnTransaction: Boolean
    private get() = mCurrentTrid != null && mCurrentPhoneNumber != null


  private fun procIncomingCallRinging(phonenumber: String?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "!!!!!!!!procIncomingCallRinging!!!!!!!")
    if (phonenumber == null || phonenumber.isEmpty()) {
      stop()
      return
    }
    val _phonenumber = phonenumber.replace("\\D+".toRegex(), "")

    showNoti(null)

    requestPutCallerid(
      _phonenumber,
      INCOMINGCALL_RINGING,
      null,
      object : IRequestPutCalleridCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(trid: String?, userinfo: CallerIdOverlay.ICallerIdViewItem?) {
          Log.d(TAG, "!!!!!!!!procIncomingCallRinging onSuccess CALL!!!!!!!trid: $trid userinfo : ${userinfo.toString()}")
          mUserInfo = userinfo
          showNoti(userinfo)


          startTransaction(trid, _phonenumber)


          if (userinfo == null) {
            overlay!!.hideView()

            endTransaction()
            return
          }

          overlay!!.showRingingView(userinfo, mCurrentPhoneNumber)
        }
      })
  }






  private fun requestPutCallerid(
    phonenumber: String?,
    eventcode: Int,
    trid: String?,
    callback: IRequestPutCalleridCallback
  ) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(
      TAG,
      "requestPutCallerid() :: $phonenumber"
    )
    val args = JsonObject()
    args.addProperty("phonenumber", phonenumber)
    args.addProperty("eventcode", eventcode)
    args.addProperty("trid", trid)
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0)
    val handle = prefs.getLong(BACKGROUND_SETUP_CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY, 0L)
    args.addProperty("callback", handle)
    CALLERID_CALLBACK = callback
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "invokeMethod() :: findCallerId :: " + args.toString())
    if(!IsStart) {
      startBackground(this)
      IsStart = true
    }
    val map = Arguments.createMap()
    map.putString("params",args.toString())
    sendEvent("findCallerId",map)

  }

  enum class ViewType {
    NONE, RINGING, CONNECTED, IDLE
  }

  interface IRequestPutCalleridCallback {
    fun onSuccess(trid: String?, userinfo: CallerIdOverlay.ICallerIdViewItem?)
  }

  companion object {
    var mPrevPhoneState = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE


    private var mCurrentPhoneNumber: String? = null


    private var mCurrentTrid: String? = null
    private var mUserInfo: CallerIdOverlay.ICallerIdViewItem? = null

    var mActivityContext : ReactActivity? = null


    private const val TAG = "CallerIDService"


    const val INCOMINGCALL_RINGING = 0

    const val OUTGOINGCALL = 3


    var IsStart = false


    private var backgroundActivityView: View? = null
    const val SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = "CallerIDService"
    private const val BACKGROUND_SETUP_CALLBACK_HANDLE_KEY = "back" +
      "ground_setup_callback"

    private lateinit var mReactContext : ReactContext;

    fun instance(_reactApplicationContext: ReactApplicationContext) {
      mReactContext = _reactApplicationContext;
    }

    fun setActivity(_activity : ReactActivity) {
      mActivityContext = _activity
    }


    @Synchronized
    fun startBackground(context: Context?) {
      IsStart = true
    }

    private fun sendEvent(eventName: String, params: WritableMap?) {
      try {
        mReactContext
          .getJSModule(RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
          .emit(eventName, params)
      } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        Log.e(
          "ERROR",
          "java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to invoke JS before CatalystInstance has been set!"
        )
      }
    }

    fun addEventListener(_method:String,value: ReadableMap) {
      val json: String = value.toString()

      if (_method == "findCallerResult") { 
        try {

          val updateBundle = Arguments.toBundle(value)
          updateBundle?.getString("trid")?.let { Log.d(TAG, "trid : $it") }
          updateBundle?.getString("userinfo")?.let { Log.d(TAG, "userinfo : $it") }
          Log.d(TAG,"carbrandname : ${Gson().fromJson(updateBundle?.getString("userinfo"),
            CallerIdVO.CallerIdUserInfoVO::class.java).carbrandname}")
          val infoJson = Gson().fromJson(updateBundle?.getString("userinfo"),
            CallerIdVO.CallerIdUserInfoVO::class.java)
          CALLERID_CALLBACK?.onSuccess(updateBundle?.getString("trid"), infoJson);
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          CALLERID_CALLBACK?.onSuccess(null, null);
        }
      } else if (_method == "findCallerResultShop") {
        try {
          val vo: TsReservation = Gson().fromJson(json, TsReservation::class.java)
          val map = Arguments.createMap()
          map.putString("techshop",Gson().toJson(vo,TsReservation::class.java))
          CALLERID_CALLBACK?.onSuccess("techshop", vo);
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          sendEvent(_method,null)
        }
      }
    }

    fun bundle2string(bundle: Bundle?): String? {
      if (bundle == null) {
        return null
      }
      var string = "Bundle{"
      for (key in bundle.keySet()) {
        string += " " + key + " => " + bundle[key] + ";"
      }
      string += " }Bundle"
      return string
    }

    var CALLERID_CALLBACK: IRequestPutCalleridCallback? = null
  }

}
```

What problems can cause the following problems?

I'm not nunderstand

Comment: var overlay: CallerIdOverlay? = CallerIdOverlay(appilcationContext)

Context issue... this mean worker thread not a main thread here.

Comment: @GobuCSG so `var overlay: CallerIdOverlay? = CallerIdOverlay(applicationContext as CallerIDService)` ??

Comment: @GobuCSG and then how to work class function ?? example : `service.startEstimationActivity` in CallerIdOverlay.kt

Comment: @GobuCSG I changed code but get error ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.reactnativecallerid.service.CallerIDService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference```

Comment: @GobuCSG so I use context in calleridoverlay.kt `mWindowManager = service.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager?     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(service.applicationContext)` but same error

Comment: Create instance inside onCreate method in your service

Comment: Call like this in your service class.... overlay=CallerIdOverlay(this).       overlay.onCreate()